# CakePHP include external php file in plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, path, include

I'm making a main app in CakePHP 1.3.10 that has a couple of plugins. In one of them, I need to use a very big array (`$array_test`) populated "manually".

The way I have it now (which works perfectly) is that I declare the array in the controller of the plugin that I want to use it in (**plugin1_home_controller.php** for example), doing something like `var $array_test = array(1,2,3,4,5...)`, and I can access it perfectly from the views in that controller.

The thing is that I would prefer having the array declared somewhere else in the plugin, since it's too big, and then load it when I need it.

So I'm trying to create a **array_test.php** file with the array declared in it, put in **/app/plugins/plugin1/webroot/php/array_test.php**, and then load it from the view using `include "/php/array_test.php"` (I also tried `include "/plugin1/php/array_test.php"` as the CakeBook says in the plugins assets section), but none of them work.

How can I get the right path? Or is there any good alternative to what I want to do? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your plugin is in the app's directory use:

```
APP_PATH.'plugins'.DS.'plugin1'.DS.'webroot'.DS.'php'.DS.'array_test.php'
```

If your plugin is installed in the common cake directory:

```
CORE_PATH.'plugins'.DS.'plugin1'.DS.'webroot'.DS.'php'.DS.'array_test.php'
```

Comment: Cool! It works! Thank you very much. I just found out that I can use `App::import('Plugins', 'plugin1.php/array_test.php');` as well, but then I have to declare the array as a property of a class. What way is better? Your way needs less code, that's for sure, but I don't know if there's any benefit of using the Import and a class...

Comment: A simple include has less overhead